# Determine Who Removed the Security Group which was Attached to EC2 machine in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-security-group, amazon-cloudtrail

### Problem Statment:

I have an EC2 machine that is running, and today I found someone removed **`one`** of the `Security Group` attached to the EC2 machine.

I wanted to know, how can we check **`who`** removed the security group from the EC2 machine.

### Solution Tried so far(CloudTrail):

1. Checked `RevokeSecurityGroupIngress` and `RevokeSecurityGroupEgress` but that is only giving what is edited(Add/Remove/Edit) in particular security group.
2. Checked `ModifySecurityGroupRules`.

> Note: Cannot use Insights and Query due to business restrictions.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it should be under [ModifyInstanceAttribute](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_ModifyInstanceAttribute.html) with a `security-group` attribute on the event that is the ARN of the security group in question.

Comment: `ModifyInstanceAttribute` didn't help in getting any useful information. In CloudTrail, Under *`Lookup attributes`*, I choose **Event Name**  **:**  **ModifyInstanceAttribute** which returns a few changes but **non** of them have anything related to the Security Group change.

Comment: Can you not simply search for all events related to that security group ID?